# How to find the maximum and minimum of a multivariable function?

Tags: analysis

I have this problem which I'm having trouble solving. I have to find the minimum and maximum of the following set:

$$A=\left\{\frac{x-y}{x+y+3} \mid x\in[-1, 1], y\in[-1, 1]\right\}.$$

Now, I feel like this problem would be much easier if the variables from the numerator and denominator were different. I would just find the minimum and maximum of the numerator and denominator, and the maximum over the minimum would be the max of the set, and min over max would be the min of the set.

However, since the variables used are the same, I don't know how to go about solving this problem, and would appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

we denoting by $$f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x+y+3}$$ the function defined on $$-1\le x\le1$$ and $$-1\le y\le 1$$ the we get the partial derivatives as
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{x+y+3-(x-y)}{(x+y+3)^2}$$ and
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{-(x+y+3)-(x-y)}{(x+y+3)^2}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With that said, this may be sad but I actually have not yet learned about partial derivatives. Is there another way of going about this?

Comment: set the partial derivatives equal to zero and then we will see

Comment: Alright, I just learned about partial derivatives so I now understand how you got those two derivatives. When you say to make the derivatives zero, do you mean that I should set each partial derivative to 0 and then solve for the corresponding variable? If so, what do I do with the y's? Do I keep treating them as constants. After that, what do I do? Do I make a linear system or something? I'm assuming I set them to zero because that is where the function has its maxima and minima, is that right? Thanks again;